# Fonts Corrupted

Tags: python, windows-10, pycharm

All of a sudden, fonts got corrupted on my python editor and I don't know what's the cause or how to go about fixing it.

OS - **Windows 10**
Editor - **PyCharm Community 2016.2.3**

Here's what I have tried so far (non of which worked)

1. Play with DPI scaling and adjusting resolution
2. Install previous version of pycharm to rule out any possibility of version specific bugs
3. Try to navigate through PyCharm settings for font configuration
4. Look up internet

This is how it looks now...

[image: Reference 1]

[image: Reference 2]

Please help if you have run into similar issue or know of a fix.

Comment: Is Windows 10 English or locale?

Comment: @nick_gabpe, it's in English.

Comment: and pycharm version are English too. Am I roght?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: You can try `"Control Panel" - "Region and Language" - "Administrative" tab -Change system locale...` and there select English US. Not sure that this help but you can try. This may required reboot.

Comment: I see that it is already set to English (United States). Also my other applications like web browser, notepad++ and SSMS are working perfectly fine. So I think this might be related to pycharm specific variable setting (like java runtime) but don't know exactly what and how.

Answer (score 2):

Few days back when I got my new laptop with Windows 10 I had tweaked registry to change default font type Segoe UI to Calibri.

All other applications were happy with this change but not PyCharm.

So I reverted the registry settings to default using:

[Reset Default System Font Settings (to Segoe UI) in Windows](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-font-default-settings-segoe-ui-windows/)

This is what it looks now.

[image: Fixed]

I wish I could have kept using Calibri, but as of now this is what worked.

Thanks to everyone who helped.